# Multiple @Before/@After with Cucumber and Spring?

Tags: spring, junit, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-jvm

I don't understand the Cucumber configuration and cannot find any example on this.

Folder structure:

```
src/
 |-test/
    |-resources/
    |  |-cucumber/
    |     |-auth/
    |     |  |-Login.feature
    |     |-contributions/
    |        |-ClearanceCertificates.feature
    |-java/
       |-de/
          |-vbg/
             |-other/
                |-again/
                   |-important/
                      |-cucumber/
                      |  |-auth/
                      |  |  |-LoginStepDefinitions.java
                      |  |-contributions/
                      |     |-ClearanceCertificatesStepDefinitions.java
                      |-CucumberBase.java
                      |-SeleniumApplicationTests.java
```

CucumberBase.java:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:build/reports/tests/test/cucumber.html"})
public class CucumberBase {}
```

SeleniumApplicationTests.java:

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
class SeleniumApplicationTests {}
```

Both `*StepDefinitions.java` have a `@Before` and `@After` defined. My assumption was that the `StepDefinitions` are matched to the `*feature`-files based on location/package.

In my tests though, the `Login.feature` executes the `@After` defined in the `ClearanceCertificatesStepDefinitions.java`.

How should this be configured properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All step definitions and hooks on the glue path are global. So all scenarios can access all step definitions on the glue path and all hooks on the glue path are executed before/after each scenario.

If you have hooks that should only be executed for a particular scenario you could use conditional hooks. To run a particular hook only for certain scenarios, you can associate a Before or After hook with a tag expression.

```
Feature: Example

  @browser
  Scenario: Open a browser window
    ...
   
  @headless
  Scenario: Make a http call
    ...
```

```java
@After("@browser and not @headless")
public void doSomethingAfter(Scenario scenario){
  // only executed after "Open a browser window"
}
```

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#conditional-hooks

---

Alternatively you can change the organization of your code.

```
 |- src/test/java/com/example/one/RunCucumberTest1.java
 |- src/test/resources/com/example/one/example-1.feature

 |- src/test/java/com/example/two/RunCucumberTest2.java
 |- src/test/resources/com/example/two/example-2.feature
  
 |- src/test/java/com/example/common/AbstractCucumberTest.java
 |- src/test/java/com/example/common/SeleniumApplicationTests.java
```

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(extraGlue = "com.example.common")
public abstract class AbstractCucumberTest {}
```

```java
public class RunCucumberTest1 extends AbstractCucumberTest {}
```

```java
public class RunCucumberTest2 extends AbstractCucumberTest {}
```

Cucumber will scan the package of the runner for glue and features so the glue and feature path can be ommited. By setting the `extraGlue` property the common configuration doesn't have to be duplicated.

Comment: Many thanks! Works very well. Using tags now.